# ffmpeg: No such file or directory exception when trying to concatenate .m4s files

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

Hi I have pretty much no idea what I'm doing and 0 experience with ffmpeg, so forgive me if I'm just being dense.

I'm trying to concatenate a bunch of .m4s files using ffmpeg, however it can't seem to find the source txt file containing the locations of all the .m4s files. I have no idea how to check where it's searching or how to change it.

The code I'm trying to use is ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt target.mp4

I have both the mylist.txt file and target.mp4 file at the root of the C: drive

Again, I don't really know what I'm doing, I just found that code on a quora thread about concatenating m4s files which is the original issue, so if anyone knows a different/better way of doing it that would be very helpful as I couldn't find much.

Answer (score 0):

follow [this guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

if the paths in the txt file are absolute you need to add `-safe 0`

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```